# Invalid value for Integer

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
my_name = 'Alessandro Tegagni'
my_age = '31'
my_height = '170 '#cm
my_weight = '82 '#kg
my_eyes = 'Brown'
my_teeth = 'White'
my_hair = 'Brown'

puts "let is talk about %s." % my_name
puts "he is %d cm tall." % my_height
puts "he is %d kg heavy." % my_weight
puts "actually that is not too heavy."
puts "he is got %s eyes and %s hair." % [my_eyes,my_hair]
puts "his teeth are usually %s depending on the coffee or tea" % my_teeth

puts "if I add %d, %d, and %d I get %d." % [my_age,my_height,my_weight,my_age+my_height+my_weight]
```

raises an error:

```
:17:in `%': invalid value for Integer(): "31170 82 " (ArgumentError)
```

What is the error?

Comment: take out the spaces after 170 and 82. also, consider them leaving outside of single quotes

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are defining your variables as strings. And using `+` on strings concatenates them, which is what you are seeing with `31170 82`. To solve this problem, assign integer values to the variables, not strings:

```
my_name = 'Alessandro Tegagni'
my_age = 31
my_height = 170 #cm
my_weight = 82 #kg
my_eyes = 'Brown'
my_teeth = 'White'
my_hair = 'Brown'
```

This should be enough to make your code work properly.

Answer (score 1):

In line:

```
puts "if I add %d, %d, and %d I get %d." % [my_age,my_height,my_weight,my_age+my_height+my_weight]
```

Each `%d` notation in the string attempts to interpret the argument passed to it by applying `Integer()` to it. This works for the first three arguments, which can be interpreted as an integer (`my_age`, `my_height`, `my_weight`). But with the fourth argument `my_age + my_height + my_weight`, the value is `"31170 82 "`, which cannot be interpreted as an integer. That is the error raised.

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply telling you that you are trying to convert something that is not an integer inside an integer format.

> :17:in `%': invalid value for Integer(): "31170 82 " (ArgumentError)

Removing the spaces will generate a valid integer, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_age = 31
my_height = 170 #cm
my_weight = 82 #kg
```

https://ideone.com/KYWgJK

just remove '' around your int and everything works fine.